# Function to combine list elements

Tags: python, python-2.x

I was working on a little project that at the end of the script would write to a CSV file. I had to create a function that would combine multiple list elements of the same size into a single one. I would like to see if there is a more efficient way of doing this since I feel the way I did might not be the most efficient one. I created the function due to the need of capturing different number instances from a large CSV file. The reason on hwy I'm using "-" is because it was easier for me to count list elements.

```
def clean(li):
    tl = len(li)#2
    amount = len(li[0].split(","))
    if tl == 1:
        return ",".join(li)
    else:     
        hold = "-," * amount
        hold = hold[:-1]
        d = hold.split(",")   
        for i in li:
            con = i.split(",")
            for z, x in enumerate(d):  
                if d[z] == con[z]:
                    pass
                elif d[z] > con[z]:                
                    d[z] = d[z]
                else:
                    d[z] = con[z]
        return ",".join(d)

a = ['-,-,17,-,-,-,', '-,-,-,17,-,17,']
b = ['-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-']   
c = ['19,-,-,-,-,-,','-,-,19,-,-,19,','-,-,-,-,19,-,']
ss = clean(a)
se = clean(b)
sq = clean(c)
```

Output:

```
-,-,17,17,-,17,-
-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,5,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
19,-,19,-,19,19,-
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review! Your question came up in the first post review queue and it looks good to me (I've corrected the spelling a bit though). Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on the need for the function, as you'll be probably asked why you chose this particular representation (semi-structured strings in a list). Hope you get good answers!

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I will elaborate more based on your advise.

Comment: What if there are multiple numbers on the same position?

Comment: Because of the file format, that would not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite hard to understand what your code is supposed to do. Let's try to progress little by little.

I've based my analysis on the test cases you have provided.

**`if tl == 1:`**

A list with a single element seems to be handled in a special way. If we replace the check with `if tl == 1 and False:`, we can see that the result is the same if we don't handle this case in a particular way.

I've removed the corresponding check.

**`hold`**

You are performing some super tricky logic involving string manipulation, list slicing and split. I realised that the whole thing does the same thing as `d = ['-'] * amount`.

**Comparison of `d[z]` and `con[z]`**

You are handling the three different cases here. Funny thing is that you have a case where you do nothing (`pass`) and one where you do something which looks like nothing to me (`d[z] = d[z]`). At the end of the day, I have the feeling that this could be written : `d[z] = max(x, con[z])`.

**Hard coded strings**

You have `','` in multiple places. If you ever want to change this, this will be pretty akward. You could store this in a variable on its own. Even better, you could make this a parameter with a default value. You have the benefit of making things easier for you as a developer of the function but also as a user of the function because it is easier to change its behavior if needed.

At this point, the code looks like:

```
def clean(li, sep=','):
    amount = len(li[0].split(sep))
    d = ['-'] *  amount
    for i in li:
        con = i.split(sep)
        for z, x in enumerate(d):
            d[z] = max(x, con[z])
    return sep.join(d)
```

**Splitting string once**

As you only care about the splitted version of the string, it would probably be interesting to split them at the very beginning so that you don't have to worry about this later on in the function.

```
splitted = [i.split(sep) for i in li]
```

**Input handling**

A few special cases could lead to troubles :

- if `len(li) == 0`, your code will crash.
- if the elements of `splitted` (which are lists of strings) have different lengths, your code will either crash (if a list is smaller that the first one) or ignore additional elements (if a list is bigger than the first one).

You might want to handle this properly.

Now, the code looks like :

```
def clean(li, sep=','):
    splitted = [i.split(sep) for i in li]
    if not splitted:
        return "invalid input" # or anything you like
    amount = len(splitted[0])
    if any(len(s) != amount for s in splitted):
        return "invalid input 2" # or anything you like
    d = ['-'] *  amount
    for s in splitted:
        for z, (dz, sz) in enumerate(zip(d, s)):
            d[z] = max(dz, sz)
    return sep.join(d)
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I fell that the way i handled it is very messy and not easy to follow

Comment: Looking at your code, I'll explore more the zip() and max, Seems like a very efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do this will be to use the magic of `zip` or `itertools.izip` with splat operator(*) as they allow us to transpose a list of lists and that's exactly what you want here:

```
from itertools import izip

def drop_until_dash(seq):
    # next() will return the first non-empty and non-dash character
    # if no such item is found then we return '-'

    return next((x for x in seq if x not in {'-', ''}), '-')

def clean(seq):
    # Create an generator that will yield list for each items split at
    # ','
    splitted = (s.split(',') for s in seq)

    # Now pass this generator to izip and it will transpose those lists for us
    # For example in the first case splitted will be:
    # [['-', '-', '17', '-', '-', '-', ''], ['-', '-', '-', '17', '-', '17', '']]
    # and then zipped will be equal to: 
    # [('-', '-'), ('-', '-'), ('17', '-'),
    # ('-', '17'), ('-', '-'), ('-', '17'), ('', '')]
    # As you can see it will return items from each column on iteration

    zipped = izip(*splitted)
    out = []
    # prevents unnecessary lookups to .append inside of the loop
    out_append = out.append

    # Now for each column (assuming you want the first non-dash and
    # non-empty character) we can write another function that
    # returns the first non-dash and 
    # non-empty(This will show up in strings with trailing ',')

    for col in zipped:
        item = drop_until_dash(col)
        out_append(item)
    return  ','.join(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I note is that your naming is too terse. What is `tl`? `li`? `hold`? `con`? `i`? `d`? `z`? `x`? I have no idea. I think `i` might stand for `item`.

Secondly, your one comment exists seemingly solely to confuse:

```
tl = len(li)#2
```

... What?

You only use `tl` once, so just replace it with `len(li)`. Your check:

```
if len(li) == 1:
    return ",".join(li)
```

shouldn't be needed so remove that too.

`hold` makes a string of the form `-,-,-,-,...` crops the final `,` and then splits it. You can just do `d = [','] * amount`. `d` seems to be what you're merging into, so call it `merged`.

You use `amount` once, so just put its value where it's used.

This does nothing:

```
        if merged[z] == con[z]:
            pass

        elif merged[z] > con[z]:
            merged[z] = merged[z]
```

It's only the last branch that you want to keep. So just write:

```
        if con[z] > merged[z]:
            merged[z] = con[z]
```

This is a `max` across the two rows, so write:

```
    merged = [max(m, c) for m, c in zip(merged, con)]
```

or even:

```
    merged = map(max, merged, con)
```

This gives:

```
def clean(rows):
    merged = ['-'] * len(rows[0].split(','))

    for row in rows:
        merged = map(max, merged, row.split(','))

    return ",".join(merged)
```

The dashes don't seem to be particularly useful at this point but do make me a little confused; if you are using them to count elements then why does

```
19,  -,  -,  -,  -,  -,
 -,  -, 19,  -,  -, 19,
 -,  -,  -,  -, 19,  -,
```

merge to

```
19,  -, 19,  -, 19, 19, -
```

with an extra `-` on the end? If this is meant to happen, the dashes seem useless for getting the count; you should just do `elem.count(',') + 1`.

Further, dashes complicate the code.

A sensible way to deal with the code is to split the fake lists into real lists. I suggest removing the dashes first:

```
rows = [row.replace('-', '').split(',') for row in encoded_rows]
```

I suggest encapsulating encoding and decoding in two reusable functions:

```
def encode_list(items):
    return ','.join(item or '-' for item in items)

def decode_list(items):
    return items.replace('-', '').split(',')
```

Further, instead of

```
for row in rows:
    merged = map(max, merged, row.split(','))
```

one can now just do

```
map(lambda *args: max(args), *rows)
```

Note that you can't do `map(max, *rows)` because `max` acts differently if it only gets once element to if it gets multiple.

This gives:

```
def clean(encoded_rows):
    rows = map(decode_list, encoded_rows)
    merged = map(lambda *args: max(args), *rows)
    return encode_list(merged)
```

It's worth noting that the real function is just

```
def clean(rows):
    return map(lambda *args: max(args), *rows)
```

but you have a decode-encode cycle around it.